# PHP Laravel multiple file upload by using two tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm building a `Laravel`-nova application and I have a `<form>` where it should be possible to upload multiple files. So I have to tables - `single_applications` and `single_application_files`. So, when I fill out the form the data gets posted correctly except the files and I have absolutely no clue why e.g. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the blade template:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('application.store') }}">

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
       <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="name" required>
    </div>
    //...and a bunch more
    //...then the file input

    <div class="form-group col">
       <div class="custom-file file">
          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="attachment-1" name="attachment_cv[]" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx,application/msword,.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="attachment-1">Add File</label>
            <div class="addBtnContainer">
               <a href="#" data-js="add" class="js-addFileField">+ Add</a>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Due to usability I don't want the `<input type="file" multiple />`, instead the user can click on `add` and with a little help from `jquery`, another file input field appears.

My `SingleApplication`-Model looks like this:

```
class SingleApplication extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
       'avatar', 'name', 'email', 'phone', 'address', 'zipcode', 'city', 
       'education', 'about', 'birthyear', 'job_category', 'status','vehicles', 'worktime', 'clothing'
    ];
}
```

And my `SingleApplicationFile`-Model looks like this

```
class SingleApplicationFile extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = [
    'attachment_cv', 'files_id', 'attachment_cv_name', 'attachment_cv_size', 'single_applications_id'
   ];
 }
```

So far so good, so I do use `axios` to do post the data, so here is how it looks:

```
 $('#singleApplication button[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append(
        "name",
        $("#singleApplication")
            .find('input[name="name"]')
            .val()
    );
    // ...etc. etc. the same with all other fields

    // HERE I FETCH THE ATTACHMENT FILES
    var attFiles = [];

    $('input[name="attachment_cv[]').each(function() {
        attFiles.push($(this).prop("files")[0]);
    });

    formData.append("attachment_cv", attFiles);


    axios.post($("#singleApplication form").attr("action"), formData)
        .then(response => {
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response.data); // DEBUG
        });

    });

 });
```

Now it comes to the controller, and here is what I think something goes wrong.

```
use App\SingleApplication;
use App\SingleApplicationFile;

class SingleApplicationsController extends Controller
{
   public function store()
   {
    $application = SingleApplication::create([
        'email' => request()->email,
        'name' => request()->name,
        'avatar' => request()->avatar,
        'phone' => request()->phone,
        'address' => request()->address,
        'zipcode' => request()->zipcode,
        'city' => request()->city,
        'birthyear' => request()->birthyear,
        'job_category' => request()->job_category,
        'education' => request()->education,
        'about' => request()->about,
        'vehicles' => request()->vehicles,
        'worktime' => request()->worktime,
        'clothing' => request()->clothing,
        'status' => request()->status,
    ]);


    if (request()->hasFile('attachment_cv')) {

        $files = request()->file('attachment_cv');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filesize = $file->getSize();

            $path = Storage::disk('local')->put('attachments/application_files', request()->file($filename));

            $application_files = SingleApplicationFile::create([
                'files_id' => $application->id,
                'single_application_id' => $application->id,
                'attachment_cv' => $path,
                'attachment_cv_name' => $extension,
                'attachment_cv_size' => $filesize,
            ]);

            new SingleApplicationFile($application_files);

            return response()->json('OK', 200);
        }
    }
}
```

So, can someone maybe tell me, what Im doing wrong? As mentioned before, all data go through except the files, the table in the database remains empty.

**UPDATE**

For some reason the request does not pass the line

```
  if (request()->hasFile('attachment_cv')) {}
```

how can that be?

Comment: Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your <form tags> [without it](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) files won't be sent with the post request

Answer (score 0):

As you need to upload the file add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form and I have noticed `request()->file($filename)` in this line

```
$path = Storage::disk('local')->put('attachments/application_files', request()->file($filename));
```

Your field name is attachment_cv not $filename. So you need try one of the following

```
$name = md5('myfile_'.date('m-d-Y_hia')).'.'.$extension; //This will save a unique file name

$path = Storage::disk('local')->put('attachments/application_files/'.$name, $_FILES['attachment_cv']['name'][$i]);
```

// increment $i according to foreach

```
$path = Storage::disk('local')->put('attachments/application_files/'.$name, $filename);
```

You can also use `$path = $filename->store('attachments/application_files');`
This will auto generate a random file name